# Converter or cable to car power supply

Tags: automotive, cables, converter

I have a PC intended to be powered by 12VDC in a car.

I wish to operate the PC from the AC mains at home. To do this I will need to connect it using a plug as shown below, and I will need a converter or other device to power it using AC mains power. (I don't know the correct name of such a device so I don't know what to search for.)

[image: Power connector for car computer]

I'd appreciate it if somebody could tell me what I should be looking for and perhaps show me an example on ebay or a similar site so I know I have understood correctly - assuming it's possible to do what I want.

Thank you

EDIT:

So here is the one copy/paste from manual:

> The AR-V6002 power subsystem converts the external DC input from vehicle to stable power rails for internal mother board, peripherals, and external I/O. The power subsystem  can be configured by either an onboard switch SW1 or software to support various power  off delay time. There are 9 power modes available for your application.
>   2.3.1 Definition:
>   1. Ignition: Ignition is a voltage input to command the power subsystem start a power on  and off cycle. It is treated as ON when voltage is above 1.1 Volts and OFF as voltage  is below 1.1 Volts. The maximum voltage input shall below 32 volts.
>   2. Remote Switch: Remote switch input is a Open/Close latch switch. It is an optional  function when the power mode is set as Mode 2, 3 and 4. When you set the power  mode as 5, 6 or 7, it works with ignition to power on or off the system. It will be treated  as ON when the switch is CLOSED. It will be treated as OFF when the switch is  OPEN.
>   3. Soft Off Delay: This is the delay time after ignition or remote switch is OFF till power  subsystem sends a turn off command to the motherboard. If ignition or remote switch  is turned ON again during this period, the power subsystem will cancel the OFF  procedure and back to operating condition.
>   4. Hard Off Delay: This is the delay time after power subsystem detects the OS has been  shut down till the standby power is turned off.

And this is a [LINK](http://global.acrosser.com/products_3/In_Vehicle_Computer/In_Vehicle_PCs/AR_V6002FL/8/139/173.html) to an actual product it has datasheet so maybe you will find all the information there.

Comment: Both shopping advice and consumer electronics support are off topic on this forum. We are focused on designing electronics, not supporting those whom purchase them. I am sorry to close your question, I hope if you get into designing electronics you return here.

Comment: @denonth  - The manual [here](http://global.acrosser.com/products_datasheet.php?gid=173)  says that voltage input is 9 to 32V and maximum wattage is 47W.  So a 12V, 4A power supply is marginally good enough and a 12V,5A or 12V,6A is better.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - thank you, but is it possible to make or buy this cable with this 3 pins?

Comment: Cables can be made. One off would usually be expensive. Agents for PC should have canles. IF you have cable for car use you could cut it in two, insert a connector pair of your choice and equip a mains power supply with same. Then you can plug PC inti either using your new style connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image: 12 V power supply with cigarette lighter plug]

It has a cord that plugs into the wall (120 Volts) in your house and a cigarette lighter jack just like in the car where you can plug anything into that you could plug into the car. It also has binding posts if you prefer to connect the wires directly. it outputs 13.8 V (which is what you will find in a running car on the nominal 12 V wires).

This particular [power supply](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2103959) is from Radio Shack.

They are available in various current (wattage) capacities depending on how much current your device requires.

---

[The manual](http://global.acrosser.com/products_datasheet.php?gid=173) says that voltage input needs to be in the range  9 to 32V and maximum wattage is 47W. 
12V power supplies are common. Thee may be sold as 13.8V supplies as that is the maximum voltage that a car battery usually reaches in normal use.

So a 12V, 4A power supply is marginally good enough and a 12V,5A or 12V,6A is better. More current capability does not hurt. [This supply](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2103960) is rated at 15A and would be suitable and is not much dearer than a 3A supply. You may wish to check that the ripple output of such supplies is OK for your system. Should be OK but some have more ripple than others.

Comment: so i only need 2 wires from that device to plug into 12V and IGN pin? this is ok, but a bit expencive

Answer (score 0):

The best option is switch the power supply inside to a AC supply. Otherwise, you can run it off of a 12 volt supply has suggested by @JonnyBoats. The IGN signal is ignition and can be switched to the 12 volt supply to turn the unit on/off or always connected to 12v to start with the power supply.

Comment: isn't there just a cable for that with this 3 connectors :(